# url rewriting not showing index page

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^doit$ doit.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ follow.php?follow=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when i try to go in the index page, everytime showing `follow.php` page, even `doit` page show this last one.

Any fix for this issue please ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond technically applies only to the first RewriteRule, so
please try using something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ follow.php?follow=$1 [QSA,L]

#RewriteConds for this rule
RewriteRule ^doit$ doit.php [L]




DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I hope be useful. Regards.